# Rails 5 strong parameters doesn't allow UploadedFile

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm porting a Rails 4 app to Rails 5 and experiencing some odd behavior with strong parameters and `Rack::Test::UploadedFile`. I have a test/controller combo that does something like this:

```rb
# The test
post images_url, as: :json, params: {
    image: {
        image: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(foo)
    }
}
```

```rb
# The controller
def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:image)
end
```

According to [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit), only permitted *scalars* pass the filter, and the explicit list of types includes `Rack::Test::UploadedFile`. So far, so good.

Except... it doesn't work. It gets filtered out. If I add a `puts params` to the controller, I see something like `{"image"=>{"image"=>{"original_filename"=>"test.jpg", "tempfile"=>"#<File:0x000056493a08dfc0>", "content_type"=>"image/jpeg"}}}`. It's a hash, not an `UploadedFile`. This is borne out digging into the actionpack code as well: it ends up as a hash there, gets turned into another `ActionController::Parameters`, and isn't considered a scalar; it's thus filtered out.

This worked fine in Rails 4 with test code like this:

```rb
post :create, format: :json, image: {
    image: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(foo)
}
```

I can't seem to get this working in Rails 5, am I missing something? Interestingly, if I remove the `as: :json` the params look correct (although my controller isn't written to handle non-json so it fails for other reasons).

Comment: For image, contentType must be 'form-data' not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The option `as: :json` causes all request parameters to be [serialized using their `to_json` methods](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4bbdad500cc6438141c668d5d8b8ad2534a46b5b/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/request_encoder.rb#L25). This is why you're getting the hash rather than the `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` object.

Sadly, the encoder doesn't recognise the `UploadedFile` class as any different.